# Input Type - Suggest

Tags: genexus

É possível capturar o texto digitado em um Edit com a propriedade Input `Type = Suggest` quando não houver `ItemValue` válido?

Ex.

```
Trn Modelo {ModeloID, ModeloNome}
Trn Objeto {ObjetoID, ObjetoNome, ModeloID*}

*ModeloID = Edit (Input Type: Suggest; Item Values: ModeloID; Item Descriptions: ModeloNome)
```

> Tabela Modelo
>
> 1 - Modelo 01
>
> 2 - Modelo 02

Ao cadastrar um Objeto e digitar 'Modelo 03'. Retornará 'Não existe Modelo'.

Como capturar a String 'Modelo 03'?

Segue exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gx Ev3 upgrade 1 + C#

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser trocar a mensagem, simplesmente crie uma regra:
`refmsg('Modelo não cadastrado.',ModeloID);`

Uma regra error se o `modeloid.isempty()` também deve funcionar.

Comment: O foco ai, não é mensagem de erro, e sim, capturar o texto digitado e inserir na tabela.